# SSRS - Report Server Configuration Exception ( System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known )

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

```
    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.RSDatabase.IsLocalDbServer(String dbServer)
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.RSDatabase.GrantRSConnectionRights()
   at ReportServicesConfigUI.RSDatabase.ChangeRSDatabase()
```

Above error came at the last point of report server data base configuration.

Path to reproduce = Report Server Configuration Manager > Database > Change Database > Progress and Finish

error occurred on "Generating Right Scripts"

Can someone please attend on this and help to go through this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You probably have misspelled the name of the target SQL Server instance. You also might check the firewall configuration of the target server.

Answer (score 1):

The server instance must be a domain. If you try to use an IP address you will get this error.

Editing the IP into my hosts file with a domain and then using that solved the issue.

Comment: This is true. I ended up using a FQDN for the server, e.g. MyServer.TheDomain.net. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

GO to the SQL Server and execute the command,
select  @@servername();
it gives you the SQL Server Instance name.
That instance name you have to provide while configuring the SSRS Report.
That's it.

Please do not use IP while configuring SSRS, just use SQL Server Instance Name.